# JProbe Plugin For Eclipse 3.7

Tags: java, eclipse, jprobe

how do I add jprobe plugin into Eclipse 3.7 ,  i have also downloaded "Quest_Eclipse-Plug-in_901", but dont know what to do now ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [How to install JProbe Eclipse plug-in](http://jprobe.inside.quest.com/pageloader.jspa?sbinPageName=install_jprobe_eclipse.htm&sbinPageTitle=JProbe%20Plugin%20for%20Eclipse%20Installation) or [JProbe Eclipse Plug-in Installation](http://www.quest.com/Quest_Site_Assets/PDF/JProbev9_EclipsePlug-in_Instructions.pdf) will help

***EDIT***:

It seems that the first link does not redirect to the correct document anymore. [JProbe Help](http://us-downloads.quest.com/Repository/support.quest.com/JProbe/9.0.1/Documentation/JProbe.pdf) is still available, it has a section *Installing the JProbe Plug-in in Eclipse*. Just in case, I will include the details here as well. Essentially you use ***Install new software...*** option to install the plugin:

- Click *Help -> Install New Software*
- Type path to *JProbe* update site and select the *JProbe* item. The site is:
  `http://www.quest.com/jprobe/Eclipseupdate/`

[image]