# Installing jProbe plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jprobe

We are currently doing performance and memory analysis for our application. We are using jProbe 9.5 to perform this analysis. Can you please provide me the steps to install the jprobe plugins for eclipse.  I have also referred to this [link] [JProbe Plugin For Eclipse 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169250/jprobe-plugin-for-eclipse-3-7),  but the links provided doesnt explain the process clearly.

Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i don't find any problem with the link provided by you.Did you follow the steps.Just open eclipse goto `Help Menu->install New software` and fill the fields same as below image.
if you have downloaded any zip file then `click on archive` and point out to your downloaded archive.

[image]

Comment: Hi - There are two links provided in the above link. one is https://www.toadworld.com/?Redirected=true. When I navigate to this link, it goes to toad world. Im not able to view any steps corresponding to jprobe installation. Also the other link provides some steps to install jprobe. But it does not work for me .

Comment: please follow the second link,in step no 5 you find the location of plugin. if you find any problem to install it just follow the solution given in my answer.

Comment: Hi I have installed the plugins in eclipse. But unable to set the jprobe configurations in eclipse.Im getting the below message[JProbe™]: Unable to read JProbe installation directory. Cannot save settings.
Please specify -vmargs -Djprobe.home=<path_to_JProbe_install_dir> options as Eclipse command line options. when I specify the command args, Im unable to apply the same and run jprobe.

Comment: Do not post follow-up questions. [please Ask a new question instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).