# Integrating jprobe with eclipse?

Tags: java, jvm, profiler, jprobe

I integrated Jprobe with eclipse Indigo as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169250/jprobe-plugin-for-eclipse-3-7). But when i try to start
tomcat from Server view under Eclipse with "Profile" option , i get below error

```
JPLauncher exits with error code 15. Please open "JProbe Server Plugin Output" in Eclipse Console view or jplauncher error logs for details.
```

Under Eclipse Console view i see below error

```
Launching C:\eclipse\binary\com.jprobe.engine.native.win32.x86_9.0.1.2011-11-28_12-13-46\bin\jplauncher.exe:01-Oct-2014 19:49:03
JProbe Error: The Java VM was not recognized, so it is not supported.
JProbe Error: Unsupported JVM for this product: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe".
JProbe Error: JVM information: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_51 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.51-b03)
```

Is one of the recent versions of  jvm i.e jdk1.7.0_51 is not supported ? I really doubt this. But not sure where is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer at this [link](https://support.software.dell.com/jprobe/kb/91156) and [link2](http://us-downloads.quest.com/Repository/support.quest.com/JProbe/8.3/Documentation/JProbePluginsForEclipse_Guide.pdf). Here are the steps

> The error "Java VM was not recognized, so it is not supported."
>   relates to issue with recognizing further updates of Java SE 7. We
>   created an fix on CR#JP-15393 and it is also already fixed on the next
>   release.
>
> In the meantime, there is a workaround to add the updates to supported
>   JVM versions:
>
> 1. In your eclipse Indigo installation folder, find and open, with some xml or text editor,
>      \binary\com.jprobe.engine.native.win32.x86_9.0.1.2011-11-28_12-13-46\bin\support\jvminfo.xml
>      file.
> 2. In the jvminfo.xml file, find "sun1.7.0".
> 3. Locate the third line "" and add "(_[0-9]+)?" at the end
>      after the last question mark, so the result is "".
> 4. Save the jvminfo.xml file.
> 5. Run your application with JProbe in eclipse again. You get a warning message "JProbe Warning: The jvminfo.xml file has been
>      modified and may not be officially supported.". Now you can attach to
>      the JProbe session from menu JProbe | Attach to Session.